# New copay on Windows 7

Tags: windows, copay

How can I install new Copay wallet to my Windows 7? 
I cannot use the microsoft app store.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried installing from source? https://github.com/bitpay/copay#desktop-linux-macos-and-windows

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copay is written in Electron which means that it is entirely cross platform by design, Windows Store is just a cute wrapping in this case. You can `git clone` it and use it with `node` and `npm` but this is boring work and `nodejs` tend to throw errors at you because the compilation process of `Copay` is designed more for a `Linux` kind of system with things like `rm`s etc in `package.json`.

1. Use `Fiddler`, `Wireshark` (on `VirtualBox`) or https://store.rg-adguard.net/ (Directly) to generate links to `*.appx` file.
2. Open the downloaded file as an archive (with `WinRaR` for instance).
3. Create a new directory in the location you find most entertaining.
4. Extract `.appx` file contents into that directory.
5. Create shortcut to `<your path>\Copay\app\Copay.exe` and run the app.

Tested for `Copay v7.0.3`.

Answer (score 0):

Download the pre-compiled windows versions from the releases tab on the github page.

https://github.com/bitpay/copay/releases

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I understand your comment in the right way you mean the downloadable exe file. It's an old version and it is deprecated. The new version is available only in the microsoft app store.