# Install Copay on Windows 7 64 bit desktop

Tags: windows, copay, installation

I have windows 7 64 bit.  I need more information.  Step by step, please.

I have reviewed the previous answers but do not understand: ([New copay on Windows 7](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/81645/new-copay-on-windows-7))

1) Exactly what to download from where
2) How to install/ run the download

The windows app store says the download requires Windows 10 + one has to have/ create a Microsoft account. (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/copay-for-windows/9mzgt30hl9df?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:regionofsystemrequirementstab)

From the previous answers, I tried downloading the zip file but cannot figure out how to install it.
Thank you

Comment: If you are uncomfortable with the instructions for CoPay, I suggest you consider using [a different wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/wallets/desktop/windows/). Electrum seems moderately popular, though I have no experience with it. See also [What types of wallet are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/81246/13866)

Comment: You don't need MS Store or any account, the wallet is written in Electron, take a look at this: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/91138/93288